# Bash adds extra single quotes in multi line variable

Tags: json, bash, shell

I am having a function in shell script which is as below where I am passing a json object as variable in curl command.

```
   get_auth_token()
    {
            user_login_json=`cat <<- EOF
    {
            "jsonrpc": "2.0",
            "method": "user.login",
            "params": {
                    "user": "$user",
                    "password": "$pword"
            },
            "auth": null,
            "id": 0
    }
    EOF`

    auth_token_json=$(curl --silent -X POST -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data $user_login_json $api_endpoint)
}
```

I am expecting it to expand as below.

```
curl --silent -X POST -H Content-type:application/json --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"user.login","params":{"user":"username","password":"some-password"},"auth":null, "id": 0}' some_url
```

However it is expanding like below and I am surprised what is wrong here.

```
curl --silent -X POST -H Content-type:application/json --data '{' '"jsonrpc":' '"2.0",' '"method":' '"user.login",' '"params":' '{' '"user":' '"username",' '"password":' '"some-password"' '},' '"auth":' null, '"id":' 0 '}' some_url
```

Since my command is getting formed wrong, I am not able to get desired output. Can someone point out where I am doing mistake.

Comment: @Inian It worked for me however i needed to add extra "$var1" in order to access their actual values inside the function. Thanks

Comment: Why are you using `cat` and a HERE document? You can simply assign a multiline string to your variable directly.

Comment: @user1934428 Its just not about mutli line string. I am passing a whole json object which contains " multiple times which was causing issues.

Comment: I know, but this could also be simplified a lot if you don't wrap the whole stuff into a `cat ....` construct. Of course Json is nasty in that it requires double quotes, but in this case you could still use a double-quote-delimited multi-line string, and just escape the double quotes which you need for making Json happy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate problem I could see is lack of quotes around the variable you are trying to use as `$user_login_json`. Double-quoting the variable should preserve the formatting as expected. But even without the quotes, it is not possible to reproduce your actual issue.

The best way is to make the function return the whole JSON string and pass it to the `--data` section as below

```
jsonDump()
{
  user="$1"; pword="$2"
  cat <<- EOF
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method": "user.login",
    "params": {
        "user": "$user",
        "password": "$pword"
    },
    "auth": null,
    "id": 0
}
EOF
}
```

And now make the function return the output directly

```
auth_token_json=$(curl --silent -X POST -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data "$(jsonDump "arg1" "arg2")" "$api_endpoint")
```